# Android Studio- Click button to change the buttons text multiple times

Tags: java, android, button

I've been trying to change a buttons' text with each click and have had success the first time the button has clicked. Have been playing around with button.setTag and button.getTag to try to transition through the state of the button clicks.

Exactly what I want to do...

Button defaults to " " at start
First click text goes to "X"
Second click text goes to "O"
Third click text goes to " " //did not try to enable this yet

Here is my code so far..

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                button.setTag(0);
                button.setText("");
                final int status = (Integer) view.getTag();
                switch (status) {
                    case 0:
                        button.setText("X");
                        view.setTag(1); //pause
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        button.setText("O");
                        view.setTag(0); //pause
                        break;
                }
            }
        });//if you know why android studio makes me add this get bonus points
    }
```

Comment: You set your tag to be 0 every time you click the button. As for your comment by the }); it's the ending of your OnClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
button.setTag(0);
button.setText("");
final int status = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

so *status* will always be `0`.

Change your method to this:

```
button.setTag(0);//do this when you first initialize the button. You can even specify this in Xml with android:tag="0"
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setText("");
         final int status = (Integer) view.getTag();
         switch (status) {
             case 0:
                 button.setText("X");
                 view.setTag(1); //pause
                 break;
             case 1:
                 button.setText("O");
                 view.setTag(0); //pause
                 break;
         }
    }

});
```

I also recommend changing tags to static variables for clarity. To do this, declare these class constants:

```
public static final int STATE_PAUSED = 0;
public static final int STATE_UNPAUSED = 1;
```

Now you can set the tag with the commands:

```
view.setTag(STATE_PAUSED);
```

or

```
view.setTag(STATE_UNPAUSED);
```

Comment: Phil it worked. For anyone who wants to see the updated code it is below. I'm going to start playing around with your second suggestion. Thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

Currently everytime you click the button you set the buttons tag to 0:

```
button.setTag(0);
```

change to this:

```
if(button.getTag() == null){
    button.setTag(0);
}
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 2;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            count++;
            if(count%3==0)button.setText("X");
            else if(count%3==1)button.setText("O");
            else button.setText("");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

How about this?
Also, I'd recommend casting all your widgets in onCreate so you only have to do it once per lifecycle.

Comment: Great suggestion. They are within the onCreate. That was tripping me up for a while. Have only been doing this for a short time.

Answer (score 0):

button.setTag(0);
        button.setText("");

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setText("");
            final int status = (Integer) view.getTag();

            switch (status) {
                case 0:
                    button.setText("X");
                    view.setTag(1); //pause
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button.setText("O");
                    view.setTag(2); //pause
                    break;
                case 2:
                    button.setText("");
                    view.setTag(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```